# How to create fully reusable layout page template in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, templates, layout

For all pages, Wordpress give us a default page template : page.php. That's clear and simple, by default all pages use this template. Then, Wordpress give us a page template system, and when we speak about **template** we think **reusable** so we think about *page layout template*.
For example : *full-width*, *page-width*, *sidebar-left*... You specifie the template to use for each page, it's ok.

But when you begin to work on a more complex web site, your content will not be a simple post (page type) inside a page template anymore. For a reason or another you have to use another feature of Wordpress : page-slug.php. Before, of course you can try to do shortcode for everything you develop, include specific plugins only for your complex page etc but ONE DAY, you will have no choice to use this page-slug.php.

Here comes the problem : the content is "more specific and complex" but you still need to use your layout template, and you can't... Of course, you hate duplicated code so you don't want to just "copy" your template inside.

If we really want a specific page, we use the page-slug.php without a page template and it do the job. Then...

**Why Wordpress don't consider the page-slug.php as pure content *when* (and only when) a page template is specified ?**

Am I missing something ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you state more directly what you are trying to do and why it doesn't work?

Comment: For example, create a page composed of :

- a piece of html & shortcode (admin WP)

- a PHP file which include this previous content and build a complex page with other stuffs

- put this PHP file into the content of the page template

Comment: You still can have the same result by adding a lot of conditional tags in your template file by that generate ugly code, especially if you have to do this for many pages. Moreover I think you should create a page template regardless of its content.

Comment: I still don't understand at all what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry if it is not clear :)
In fact I could present the problem in a very easier way : build a page-home.php AND using a page template. In that case, the page-home.php is the speacial home page but is NOT the fully page, just the content, inserted in a common template.

Comment: WP don't allow that, so I am asking why ? Currently, creating a page-slug.php is exactly the same as creating a unique template and use it once for a page. And as soon as you use page-slug feature, you can't re-use your templates that is very disapointing ! So, to create many complex page with the same template (page layout template) the only solution I see is to do a lots of widget area and configure them to be displaying on the good page... the generate ugly code in your template, especially because your template will be dependant of your specific content.

Comment: The display Widget plugin helps to go cleaner but I still  don't like this solution ^^ Hope it is clear this time ;)

Comment: Sorry, I still don't think I get it.  You have a template, and then a different template?  And you want to use both?